# why rustc compile complain my simple code "the trait std::io::Read is not implemented for Result<File, anyhow::Error>"

Tags: rust, avro

Sorry for my noob rust question.

I'm working on a project regarding avro file manipulation tool based on avrow. I see the popular compile error happen on header reading. I see avrow_cli works good but I don't understand why avrow_cli handles that well. Could someone please point out what's wrong? Thank you.

Below is a piece of code and error msg.

```
use std::env;
use avrow::Header;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    println!("Hello, {}!", &args[1]);

    let mut file = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open(&args[1]);

    let header = Header::from_reader(&mut file);
    println!("{}", header.schema());
}
```

```
   Compiling avro-dump-schema-rs v0.1.0 (/home/shuduo/work/avro-rs)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<File, std::io::Error>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:38
   |
13  |     let header = Header::from_reader(&mut file);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `Result<File, std::io::Error>`
   |
  ::: /home/shuduo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/avrow-0.2.1/src/reader.rs:638:27
   |
638 |     pub fn from_reader<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<Self, AvrowErr> {
   |                           ---- required by this bound in `Header::from_reader`

error[E0599]: no method named `schema` found for enum `Result<Header, AvrowErr>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:14:27
  |
14 |     println!("{}", header.schema());
  |                           ^^^^^^ method not found in `Result<Header, AvrowErr>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `avro-dump-schema-rs`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenOptions::open()` returns a `io::Result<File>` instead of just `File`. You have to check if the `open()` operation was successful before being able to work with the file.

The simplest way to get the file is to call `.unwrap()` or `.expect()` on the result, which will cause the application to panic (i.e. crash) in case `open()` returned an error

```
 let mut file = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open(&args[1])
        .expect(&format!("Failed to open {}", args[1]));
```

Or you can try to gracefully handle the error:

```
let result = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open(&args[1]);

    // you can use `match` to extract the OK/Err cases
    match result{
        Ok(mut file) => {
            let header = Header::from_reader(&mut file);
            println!("{}", header.schema());
        }

        Err(e) => {
            // handle the error
        }
    }

    // or you can use `if let` if you are interested only in one of the enum variants (OK or Err)
    if let Ok(file) = result{
        let header = Header::from_reader(&mut file);
        println!("{}", header.schema());
    }
```

The same is valid for your second error message - `from_reader()` returns a `Result` which you should handle.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I applied your solution with a little modification and see the program works now.